# What sounds (not frequency!) can dogs hear?

Tags: audio-recording, recording, pitch-shifting, high-frequency, ultrasone

I know dogs can hear well over 50khz.

I've been searching for a while now for actual examples of things they are able to hear but we can't. There's a lot of generated sounds like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qNf9nzvnd1k) but that's not what I'm looking for.

Can anyone tell or show **what kinds of objects or events they can hear?** The point is to get an idea of the how the world sounds to a dog. I'm assuming it's a lot busier, but what 'texture' do those other sounds give? By that I don't just mean knowing the pitch, but samples of it. Either pitch shifted so I can hear them (like [this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntlGkIvH4o4)) or in their original format and I'll just shift them myself.

Secondly, **is there a way to record such high-pitch sounds with home level equipment?** I can afford to spend *some* money on a better microphone than what's in my headset and/or phone... but obviously it's not going to be professional/research level, nor specialized like a [bat recorded](https://www.wildlifeacoustics.com/store?slider2=song-meter-sm4bat-fs#song-meter-sm4bat-fs).

I should not that i don't necessarily need to get the full range up to 60 or 75 khz, something going up to 40 or even 30khz would make me happy. Just to get a bit of an idea of what lies beyond our human limits, you know?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that most sounds dogs hear are still focused below 20 kHz, with only some extra overtones that reach higher. With humans it's also this way: we only can properly distinguish sounds up to about 8 kHz. Higher frequencies are still well *sensible*, but they don't carry much useful information for us, mostly just a feeling of openness / clearness / ambience, or else just incomprehensible chirping.

Therefore, to just get an idea of what sounds dogs hear it's probably not necessary to have equipment with perfect supersonic performance. It suffices if you can capture 20~25 kHz really precisely, which is possible with a normal high-quality condenser mic and 96 kHz audio interface. Then shift those barely-human-audible sounds into the *well-human-audible* range, like 3 kHz.